# XPS13 will not suspend with kernel 4.19

Tags: 18.04, kernel, suspend, xps

After installing the newest kernel, 4.19 on Ubuntu 18.04, I found that my XPS13 doesn't want to suspend. The screen gets dark and immediately bright again. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Although technically off-topic question, I had same problem today with Kernel `4.14.78-generic` which I installed to fix problems suspending with supported kernel `4.13.0-36-generic`.

I created this script: `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

Then mark as executable using:

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd
```